# autounlock luks encrypted drives upon startup with keyfile

Tags: 16.04, encryption, luks, zfs

i have a raidz2 zpool across 6 disks. i am using ubuntu server 16.04 LTS and i want to encrypt those disks with luks and have the system decrypt them on startup, so that zfs can use them.

how exactly do i configure luks so that upon startup it automatically decrypts those drives using a keyfile (generated with `dd if=/dev/urandom`...) stored on the root of the boot drive.

i'd also like for each drive to have a different key file. preferribly sha-512 or, heck, even something higher would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in `/etc/crypttab`, something very similar to `/etc/fstab`

Just have a look at the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/crypttab.5.html).

So a line like that would do it.

```
myzfs UUID=e758456d-eb80-4eea-947c-9ac914643b61 /root/mykeyfile luks
```

where the UUID is the uuid of your LUKS volume, that you can find with `blkid`.

The unencrypted LUKS volume is available at `/dev/mapper/myzfs`. The name you gave to it above, in `crypttab`

Don't forget to add a line in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/myzfs /where/to/mount/it  fstype defaults  0 2
```